# Lua lcurses missing tutorial/axamples

Tags: lua, ncurses

I've installed lcurses (luarocks + luajit) but I'm not able to find any tutorial.

I'm reading about [ncurses with C language](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO)  trying to replicate code on lua 
but the lua porting is not a  C library direct match.

Here are the two "Hello World" example:
lua version

```
package.path = package.path .. ';/opt/luarocks_pkg/share/lua/5.1/?.lua';
package.cpath = package.cpath.. ';/opt/luarocks_pkg/lib/lua/5.1/?.so';

local curses = require('curses'); 
local os = require('os');

local function main()

  --start curses mode
  curses.initscr()
  --disable line buffering
  curses.raw();
  --switch off echoing
  curses.echo(false);

  --initialize standard screen object
  local stdscr = curses.stdscr()  
  --clear screen
  stdscr:clear();
  --move cursor at (10,10) and print, here only update the stdscr structure
  stdscr:mvaddstr(10,10,'Hello World');
  --force curses system to dump the contents on the screen
  stdscr:refresh();
  --wait for keyb input
  stdscr:getch();
  --frees the memory taken by curses sub-system and its data structures and puts the terminal in normal mode
  curses.endwin();

  return(0);
end
main()
```

C version

```c
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{   
    initscr();          /* Start curses mode          */
    printw("Hello World !!!");  /* Print Hello World          */
    refresh();          /* Print it on to the real screen */
    getch();            /* Wait for user input */
    endwin();           /* End curses mode        */

    return 0;
}
```

Replicating C code in lua require a lot of time (to learn how to use lcurses), so I'll appreciate  if someone can help me by reporting where I can find a ***lcurses lua tutorial***.

Comment: Do You think that when a developer needs to use a library (like lcurses) the missing tutorial/how-to is not a problem ? Well you are a lucky men, a real genius. But not all developers are genius. The missing tutorial for me is a great problem, so what are the suggestions to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Try [lcurses documentation](http://www.pjb.com.au/comp/lua/lcurses.html). It indicates that the API is the same so you should be able to get the details from your system's curses or ncurses man doc. If you can't do "man ncurses" or "man curses" (as documented on that link), then you can surely find some online versions:

- [Same as above, but hyperlinked](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html) to actual function docs
- [Introduction to ncurses](http://www.smnd.sk/anino/programming/c/ncurses-intro.html)
- [Ncurses howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)
- [ncurses faq](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html)
- [Programmers Guide to ncurses](http://www.c-for-dummies.com/ncurses/)

The intro to ncurses and the howto should provide what you need. Beyond that tou will have to purchase the book. Beyond that you are out of luck, so either way this answer should be closed.

Comment: thanks very much, is what I'm doing, reading the C source to  understand how use the lcurses, but it is what I'want to avoid. It requires to much time.

Comment: @msalese Not sure what you mean, the above link is not the C source, it is the actual documentation for the Lua version. The links from there to the lcurses.c have nothing to do with documenting the API. I've updated the post with more info.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake, well reading [lcurses.c](http://www.pjb.com.au/comp/lua/lcurses_c.html) and C tutorial is what I'm doing. Thanks for book suggestion.

Comment: @msalese so do this answer your question? if not, please be specific about what is missing.

Comment: "Programmers Guide to ncurses" is a nice advice (I will buy a copy), but now I'm giving a look at [pjb.com](http://www.pjb.com.au/comp/lua/lcurses_c.html#lcw_idlok) (lcurses documentation) reading the lcurses.c file. At the moment this is the only way to go because a real tutorial on lcurses is missing.

Comment: @msalese I don't see why the intro is not sufficient. I added a link to the official how-to and FAQ. There is nothing else beyond those at the moment.

Comment: Yes I know, I thank you very much for help, I'm reading the docs that you gave me, and I'm writing some example code to learn how to use the library.

Comment: On github I found someone that is working on porting ncurses on luajit using ffi, here the [link](https://github.com/sd-/luajit/blob/master/extlib/ffi/curses.lua).